# My React component doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an app on a Node/Express server and React for the front-end. I started with a very simple component but it doesn't render. Anyone can tell me why this is happening?

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.30.7/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--Load React and D3 script here-->    
    <script type="text/babel" src="/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <!--link custom css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>My Dashboard</h1>
        <!--Initialise React app here-->
        <div id="app">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the dashboard.js with the React component:

```
/*global React*/
/*global ReactBootstrap*/
/*global ReactDOM*/

alert("hello world");

const App = React.createClass({
//parent component to render all elements and hold state
    getInititialState(){
        return{

        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){


    },

    render: function(){

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Chart Here</h1>  
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
        );

    }

});//App component

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.26",
    "node-wit": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you missed App in the render? `ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));`

Comment: Sorry, was an error in the formatting here on Stack Overflow. I actually did have App in the render

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No errors in the console after installing babel

Comment: the funny thing is the alert("hello world"); doesn't work either, so maybe the whole file is not loading...

Comment: include the **babel standalone script** in `index.html` file it will work, use this: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>`

Comment: @MayankShukla works! thanks

Comment: So I actually don't need all the babel dependencies server side?

Comment: Once you've gotten the basic grasp of React, you should look into using a bundling system like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). They will help you combine JS modules (like React and React-DOM) into a single JS file with your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thanks

include the babel standalone script in index.html file it will work, use this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone‌/6.24.0/babel.js"></‌​script>
```